# How to Change Powershell Nested WMI Class Property?

Tags: powershell, wmi

Say I have a MOF file defined as:

```
class TARGET_INFO
{
    [WmiDataId(1),
     MaxLen(31),
     Description(".") : amended
    ] string HardwareId;

    [WmiDataId(2)] uint32 Policy;
};

class DEFAULT_POLICY
{
    [WmiDataId(1),
     read, write,
     Description(".") : amended
    ] uint32 NumberDevices;

    [WmiDataId(3),
     read, write,
     MaxLen(31),
     Description(".") : amended,
     WmiSizeIs("NumberDevices")
    ] TARGET_INFO TargetInfo[];
};
```

`Get-WmiObject -namespace root\wmi -class DEFAULT_POLICY` can give me an instance which has an array TargetInfo.
I want to modify one of the TargetInfo element's Policy property to 1 when this element has HardwareId equal to "blabla".
How to achieve this?
I tried both Set-WmiInstance and Put(), but none of them works. I always got different errors.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Whenever your question contains words like "error" or "exception" or "access violation", it's extremely helpful if you post the **exact** error or exception you got, along with the **exact** error messages. It makes your question more clear, and gets you answers much faster. Please edit your question and include that information, along with what you actually tried with `Set-WmiInstance` and `Put`. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the properties directly:

```
foreach( $targetInfo in $defaultPolicyInstance.TargetInfo )
 {
      if( $targetInfo.HardwareId -eq "blahba" )
      {
           $targetInfo.Policy = 1
      }
 }
```